# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int while incrementing

Tags: sql, casting, insert

Was wondering if you can correct my syntax.

```
update TestTable 
set test_person = CAST(test_person as Varchar = 'TEST' (50)) + 1
```

Im trying to update all columns in a table and increment it by 1 (hence the cast since the column is a string).

Comment: What database are you using? Please add a sample showing before & after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-SQL

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 0

UPDATE TestTable
SET test_person = 'Test' + CAST(@counter AS VARCHAR(16)), @counter = @counter + 1
```

Comment: This one's great, only if I knew of this earlier... it could have saved me so many trouble +1

Comment: ahh cool didn't know you could increment a variable in a batch

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test1' to data type int

Comment: So the `test_person` column is an integer type? To stick text in it you would need to change its column definition

Comment: Sorry was just being picky. int columns can be incremented without the string 'test'. 

Thanks for the fast replies guys.

Answer (score 2):

Something I've done in the past to do incrementing values in a string column is something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f0f5/2

```
create table testTable (id int primary key identity(1,1), test_person varchar(100))

insert into testTable (test_person)
select 'bob loblaw'
union all select 'Buster Bluth'
union all select 'Jason Bateman'
union all select 'gob'
union all select 'Lucille #2'

update testTable
set test_person = 'test ' + convert(varchar(30), id)

select * from testTable
```

results:

```
ID  TEST_PERSON
1   test 1
2   test 2
3   test 3
4   test 4
5   test 5
```

note this works when your table has an identity primary key. You did not give your entire table schema, but if it does not have this identity primary key you could do something similar by creating a temp/variable table to hold your data that *does* have an int primary key to do the same thing.

Another option would be to use a loop/cursor to do your population... but that's kind of a pain to write.

Another option would be to use ROW_NUMBER which is sql server (not sure about others).  Without the full table schema i can only give an example of how to accomplish:

seen in fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f0f5/5

```
update testTable
set test_person = 'test ' + convert(varchar(30), rowNum)
from testTable
inner join (
    -- create an incrementing number for each row
    select row_number() over(order by test_person) as rowNum, test_person
    from testTable
) rows on testTable.test_person = rows.test_person

select * from testTable
```